# OAuth.io with Github Enterprise

Tags: github-enterprise, oauth.io

It seems like OAuth.io providers (all here: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/tree/master/providers) are static files; and the thing with GitHub Enterprise is, the domain name is not github.com, but something different for each customer. Is there a way to make OAuth.io work with a provider whose domain name is always different, such as for the GitHub Enterprise use case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Shopify provider implementation which have the same problematic

https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/blob/master/providers/shopify/conf.json

We added a parameter `shop`

```
"parameters": {
   "shop": "string",
   ...
}
```

This parameter is configurable in OAuth.io when setting API keys:

[image]

and this parameter can be reused in URLs:

```
`"url": "https://{shop}.myshopify.com",`
```

Feel free to make a pull request if you have the time to add Github Enterprise to the list of OAuth providers !